# How to use fixed matrix in Eigen?

Tags: eigen

I have a big matrix which is 1000*500. But how to use Eigen fixed matrix for speed up? The dynamic matrix is slow.

Answer (score 8):

Using fixed size matrices for such large matrices is meaningless. Recall that the advantages of fixed-size matrices are 1) allocation on the stack if requested, and 2) explicit unrolling.

If you think the computation you are performing is too slow, then be specific about your computation. Moreover, make sure you benchmark with compiler optimisations ON. Because of the heavy use of templates, Eigen is particularly slow in debug mode.

Finally, for the record, here is how you can create a fixed size matrix of arbitrary size, e.g., a `6x8` matrix of doubles:

```
Matrix<double, 6, 8> mat;
```

Comment: But if I want a 1000*1000 matrix. Eigen reports a error "OBJECT_ALLOCATED_ON_STACK_IS_TOO_BIG". My platform is x64 Linux.

Comment: yes, as I said, it is not recommended at all to allocate such big objects on the stack. you can bypass the hardcoded limit by defining EIGEN_STACK_ALLOCATION_LIMIT to the limit in bytes. However, you might also have to play with the compiler/system options to increase the size of the stack! and as I said you'll get zero performance increase...

Comment: One advantage fixed sized large matrices would have is that the compiler could tell the matrix had a size divisible by 4 or 8 and would be able to make simplified SSE code which didn't have to worry about the extra values at the end which were not divisible.

Comment: what if we `new` such 1000*1000 fixed-size matrix on the heap? any perf gain?

Comment: no advantages at all, better use `MatrixXd(1000,1000)`